# Sacar datos de una variable con foreach

Tags: php, foreach

Buen dia a todos, tengo un problema, estoy mandando varios datos en una variable atravez de un formulario

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y recibo los datos en un archivo de php

```
$codproducto = $_POST['codproducto'];
$cantidad = $_POST['cantidad'];
$precio = $_POST['precio'];
$subtotal = $_POST['subtotal'];
$abono = $_POST['abono'];
$total = $_POST['total'];
$token = $_POST['token'];
$usuario = $_SESSION['idUser'];
$idcliente = $_POST['idcliente'];
$idalumno = $_POST['idalumno'];
```

y lo que quiero hacer es que me muestre todos los datos de la variable codcodproducto

pero no logro sacarlos con foreach

y estos seria los datos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y  el foreach me tira el error que aparece en la imagen

```
foreach ($codproducto as $no => $value) {
        echo "No: $no; valor: $value ";
    }
```

Comment: ¿Podrías subirnos como tienes montado tu `foreach`? También estaría bien contar con el contenido de tu variable en un formato que podamos copiar para poder hacer pruebas. Las imágenes no suelen ayudar a que la gente pueda reproducir tu problema.

Comment: Por favor sustituye las imágenes por el texto del código, es más fácil para poder ayudarte. Gracias.

Comment: No me deja agragar mas codigos

Comment: El elemento HTML `codproducto` no está guardando un array, para que lo haga tienes que ponerlo así: `name="codproducto[]"`  Puedes hacer una prueba con `var_dump($codproducto);` para  que veas lo que hay realmente.